# Amazon's AWS Mobile SDK for Android and its S3 Upload Utility is not reporting any errors, any idea why?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-asynctask

I've been running into a problem using the [AWS Mobile SDK version 2.2.15](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/). After carefully looking at their own [S3TransferUtilitySample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples), I have made a couple attempts to get a file uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket on my own.
​
My first attempt was to try calling the TransferUtility's `.upload()` method from within Android's own AsyncTask, inside the `doInBackground()` method. No success there, and after [reading about this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/93), it inspired me to try moving the SDK calls outside of the AsyncTask and into the UI thread under `onPostExecute()` in suspicion that the call itself is asynchronous and the AsyncTask is running garbage collection on the AWS SDK objects. Still no luck, no exceptions are being thrown, and no indication of anything going wrong aside from the file not actually uploading.
​
My second attempt was following [this exact example](https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-amazon-s3-to-android-tutorial/). I downloaded the source and was able to supply the application with the correct identity pool ID, region, bucket, key, and a test jpeg file. I ran the application and the calls were being made. The file made it to AWS S3 without any issues.
​
I copied their exact methods into a helper class of my application, and made all the AWS SDK objects a static field of the class, but I am still running into the same issue of no exceptions being thrown. I ended up making the fields non-static and instantiating the helper class as an object in my main activity, safely assuming that the object would not be treated with garbage collection. Still nothing! No indication of failure from these calls!
​
I decided to get really generous with logging using Android's `Log.i()` method, watching every step of the way, and it even makes it to the TransferUtility's `.upload()` method, but even having the TransferListener set and full of logging lines, there is no status change, `onError()` is not being called. TransferUtility's `.upload()` and its resulting TransferObserver object is not reporting anything like it was running the test application.
​
Here are a couple things to note:
* The correct identity pool ID is being used here, no issue with that
* I have tried using both version 2.2.15 as well as 2.2.13
* All dependencies included are .jar files, the project is not Gradle (yet)
* The service is declared in the manifest just as it was in the examples
* There are no build errors, Android Studio builds the project just fine
* The TransferListener object is not firing `onStateChanged()`, `onProgressChanged()`, nor `onError()`
​
Has anyone encountered such a strange issue with AWS S3 SDK? Any suggestions on how I can better debug this issue?

Here's the class right now:

```
public class AmazonS3Helper
{
    Context context;

    public String bucket;
    public String key;

    public File file;

    public AmazonS3 s3;
    public TransferUtility utility;

    public AmazonS3Helper(JSONObject p, Context c)
    {
        Log.i("tag", "new AmazonS3Helper object");

        this.context = c;

        try
        {
            bucket    = p.getString("bucket");
            key        = p.getString("key");


            this.file = new File(
                c.getExternalFilesDir(null),
                "nn_temp_photo.jpg");

            credentialsProvider();
            setTransferUtility();

            upload();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.i("tag", "Error in new AmazonS3Helper object: " + x.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void credentialsProvider()
    {
        Log.i("tag", "Providing credentials");

        try
        {
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                this.context,
                // This has been verified to return the correct identity pool
                MyApplicationClass.getPreference("aws.credentials"),
                Regions.US_EAST_1);

            setAmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.i("tag", "Error in providing credentials: " + x.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setAmazonS3Client(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider)
    {
        Log.i("tag", "Setting amazon s3 client");

        try
        {
            s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
            s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.i("tag", "Error in setting amazon s3 client:" + x.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setTransferUtility()
    {
        Log.i("tag", "Setting transfer utility");

        try
        {
            utility =
                new TransferUtility(
                    s3,
                    this.context);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.i("tag", "Error in setting transfer utility: " + x.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void upload()
    {
        Log.i("tag", "uploading");

        try
        {
            TransferObserver transferObserver = utility.upload(
                bucket,
                key,
                file
            );

            transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.i("tag", "Error in uploading: " + x.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver)
    {
        Log.i("tag", "transferObserverListener");

        try
        {
            transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state)
                {
                    Log.i("tag", state + "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal)
                {
                    int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                    Log.i("tag", percentage + "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.i("tag", "error");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Log.i("tag", "Error in transferObserverListener: " + x.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I forgot to mention, but the version of Android this is being tested on is Android Lollipop 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 2.2.15. Some IO exceptions aren't reported. It is fixed in 2.2.16. Would you please try the latest version?

Comment: I gave that a shot. Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Would you please provide the full code? I don't see anything wrong in your code here. If sample app works fine, I think you may not configure your app correctly to use transfer utility.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been solved and is entirely unrelated to the code itself. What was happening was that I was declaring the `com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService` in the library's manifest, but the child apps also needed it in their manifest.

I found this out by dropping the sample Activity straight into my application, and realizing the child apps also needed this activity declaration. The child apps have no code themselves, but without the declaration in their own manifest, they are unaware the activities/services being referenced exist. In this case, Amazon was silently refusing to upload because the service wasn't declared for the specific application.